# An Intent extra can retain changes?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, serialization

In a called activity I get an ArrayList from an Extra passed in the Intent by the calling activity:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
itemList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) in
                .getSerializableExtra("list_content");
```

then I add or remove some items to the ArrayList like

```
itemList.add(map);
```

I see that after a device's rotation, that is the activity is destroyed an recreated, recalling in `onCreate()` the same `getSerializableExtra()` from the Intent returns all the changes to the ArrayList made by the previous instance.

- How is it possible, how the changes are retained in a Serialized object?
- Might be this an alternative to `onSaveInstanceState()` , what pros and cons?

Comment: Did you try cloning it and using ?

Comment: I dont want cloning it, if the Extra retains the changes it is perfect for me. I just would like understand how it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the sourcecode for `Intent`, you'll see when accessing extras, you're [actually retrieving](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.getSerializableExtra%28java.lang.String%29) them from a `Bundle`. [Internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/Bundle.java#Bundle.getSerializable%28java.lang.String%29) the `Bundle` [retrieves the serializable object](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/BaseBundle.java#BaseBundle.getSerializable%28java.lang.String%29) from a `Map<String, Object>`.

The `Bundle` is managed by Android and kept alive during context switches so when you retrieve the `ArrayList`, you're actually retrieving a reference to the `ArrayList` in that `Map<String, Object>`. That's why when you make changes to the `ArrayList`, they're persisted through orientation changes and not lost.

As to whether or not it's good practice to modify variables from your `Intent` bundle, I'd advise you to save the updated `ArrayList` during `onSaveInstanceState`, and then load from your `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate`. Doing so helps prevent cases where this behaviour may surprise you or other co-developers in the future working with this code.

Comment: so in the Intent's Bundle the framework mantains a map to already deserialized objects?

Comment: yes, though using the word "deserialized" is a little misleading, because the object is never actually "serialized" in the first place. The [putSerializable()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/BaseBundle.java#BaseBundle.putSerializable%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.io.Serializable%29) method just puts the object straight into the map.

Comment: thanks, but I dont understand: if the object is never serialized/parceled it means that the called activity even retains a reference to object passed by the calling activity? So the changes will be reflected even accessing the object from the calling activity?

Comment: you're right, there must be some serialization otherwise there would be references everywhere! I just looked in the source a bit more, and it seems the objects in `mMap` aren't serialized until [writeToParcelInner()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/BaseBundle.java#BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner%28android.os.Parcel%2Cint%29) is called. So when the Bundle is serialized, it serializes all the objects it needs to - kind of a lazy serialization.